# Updating an Email Address in All Contacts (All Subscribers)

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contactbuilder

We have a Journey that uses an Automation Studio Audience. The Automation was Run Once. An Email went out correctly to EmailAddress 1. Then the EmailAddress 1 was updated to EmailAddress 2. After a Wait Activity (1 hour) a second email was sent. The email went to the original EmailAddress 1 not the updated EmailAddress 2. In addition the All Contact record still shows the original EmailAddress 1.

The Journey Settings show Use email attribute from Entry Source. Shouldn't the 2nd email have gone to EmailAddress 2?

How does an email address get updated in All Subscribers and/or All Contacts? Support is telling me it has to be an API call or manually.

Comment: Is the subscriber actually updating their email address via the preference/profile center, in this example?

Comment: Check the journey setting might be set to use the email address from that de and not the channel address order

Comment: You might also need to set up and automation to update the allsubscibers when the email changes... it's a pain.

Comment: The email address gets updated externally then pushed over through the API to a "master DE". The Journey Automation updates the Journey Entrance DE.  The Journey is set to use the DE (which is updated to the new Email Address).

Answer (score 1):

So I got this working, but not sure if it is the way to go. Here’s what I did.

I created a Population DE, basically a filtered DE from the Contacts DE where Email Address is not null. Then I added that Filter to the Automation. Basically keeping all 3 DEs (Contacts, Journey Entry, and Population) current with the Email Address updated. Then, I added the Population DE to the Channel Address Order under Contacts Configuration as the #1 Order.

1. I added a Contact (C-001 – joe@somewhere.com) and ran the Automation. The first email was sent to joe@somewhere.com as expected.
2. I then updated the C-001 Contact Email Address to joe@somewhereelse.com and ran the Automation again. This updated the Email Address in all DEs.
3. After the 1 hour wait the second email was sent to joe@somewhereelse.com as expected and the All Contacts and All Subscribers Email Address for Contact Key/Subscriber Key C-001 was updated to joe@somewhereelse.com as expected.

Do you see any issues this may cause that I’m not thinking about?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the channel address order change you have done will work. But with the august release, now it's easy to manage this. On the settings screen for a journey, you can now define a specific email address contained in a population that you want to use for a journey. You no longer need to configure the Channel Address Order for use with email sends in Journey Builder. We recommend this option for contacts who registered with Contact Builder prior to injection into the journey.

Refer to August release changes here : http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/release_notes/august_2017_release/journey_builder/

Hope this helps.